# htaccess url masking mod rewrite instead of VirtualHost File

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to mask the URL of all the pages so that when accessing them:

- `https://example.com/folder1/folder2`
- `https://example.com/folder1/folder2/browse`
- `https://example.com/folder1/folder2/details`

is displayed as:

- `https://example.com`
- `https://example.com/browse`
- `https://example.com/details`

I only want to mask `/folder1/folder2` of all the pages.

I have this on `.htaccess` but it only works for:

```
https://example.com/folder1/folder2
```

is displayed as:

```
https://example.com
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder1/folder2/
RewriteRule (.*) /folder1/folder2/$1 [L]

Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</IfModule>
```

Hope someone can help me

**Edit.**

There is another `.htaccess` which is located in `folder2`:

(The first `.htaccess` is located in the root folder)

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /

# Do not process images or CSS files further
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico|mp3|ogg|woff?2)$ - [L]

# Leave /admin and /install static
RewriteRule ^(admin|install).*$ - [L]

# Rewrite web pages to one master page
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [B=\ ;,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [B=\ ;,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? index.php?page=$1&id=$2&subpage=$3 [B=\ ;,QSA,L]
```

Comment: You need `RewriteEngine On` in the 2nd .htaccess file inside folder2

Comment: ```RewriteEngine On``` is already activated. I have edited the second .htaccess completely above, so that you can see the whole content.

Comment: What actually happens for "other" URLs? Simply a 404? An error? Is the 2nd `.htaccess` file being invoked at all? Are `.htaccess` files enabled this subdirectory? To clarify, the URL you are requesting is of the form `example.com/<something>` and not `example.com/folder1/folder2/<something>`? When requesting `https://example.com/` then the 2nd `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory isn't doing anything as `index.php` should be called by mod_dir (the `page` URL parameter will not be present for such requests).

Comment: This does not make _any_ sense: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://example.com$`. A host name never contains a protocol scheme.

Comment: @ MrWhite
so after waiting a while, both subfolders are masked. Now the call of:


 - `example.com/browse`

or 

 - `example.com/details`

without 

 - `/folder1/folder2/`

to call up is possible.

Comment: But ... 
There is still no rewriting of the entire page urls. The homepage still redirects all url calls with /folder1/folder2/ in the browser.

I have otherwise customized this via the apache config, but I would like to find a solution via .htaccess for  find.


 - `Options FollowSymLinks

AllowOverride All

Order allow,deny

allow from all
`